# Firebase Realtime database from android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to connect with firebase realtime database from android but unable to save data in firebase .
we have multiple application in one project in firebase so as database with different db url . to access database

this code is for genrating token

```
  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        token = task.getResult().getToken();

                        Log.e("token", token);
                    }
                });
```

this is for save data in firebase

```
  try {
                        //Save the location data to the database//
                        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("firebase db path").
                                getReference("user" + authref.getUid());
                        ref.child(token);
                        Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                        if (location != null) {
                            FirebaseLocationDTO locdto = new FirebaseLocationDTO();
                            locdto.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
                            locdto.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());                           
                            locdto.setOsVersion(Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
                            locdto.setUserId(userId);
                            locdto.setAppVersionName(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
                            locdto.setAppType(BaseConstant.FIREBASE_APP_TYPE);

                            ref.child(token).setValue(locdto);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception E) {
                        Log.e("error fb",E.toString());
                     
                    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to see if you get an error when the task is not successful?

Answer (score 0):

Have you allowed read/write in `Firebase Realtime Database Rules`

Comment: yes both are true